# Why does `date` ignore TZ environment variable?

Tags: date, raspbian, timezone, date-utility

On Ubuntu 18.04, I have the following behavior of `date`:

```
$ date --version | head -n1
date (GNU coreutils) 8.28
$ date
Вт окт  8 13:18:18 MSK 2019
$ TZ=UTC date
Вт окт  8 10:18:23 UTC 2019
```

So far so good. But now I'm trying to do the same on Raspbian 9:

```
$ date --version | head -n1
date (GNU coreutils) 8.26
$ date
Tue Oct  8 13:18:50 MSK 2019
$ TZ=UTC date
Tue Oct  8 13:18:51 MSK 2019
```

What could be the reason for Raspbian version of `date` to ignore the `TZ` environment variable?

Comment: Use `TZ=UTC0 date` if you want UTC date portably. The defines a zone named "UTC" with a 0 offset from UTC. While `TZ=UTC` could be anything.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks, this also helps.

Comment: See also [How can I get a formatted date for a UNIX timestamp from the command line](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/948)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of two possible causes:

1. the file `/usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC` is not present or is corrupted on your Raspbian 9, so `glibc` fails to implement the TZ variable setting and falls back to system default timezone,
2. you may have a previously-configured TZ variable that has been marked as read-only, so your attempt to change it won't take effect.

Comment: Indeed, `dpkg -V tzdata` reveals that exactly this file was changed. And comparison of hashes shows that for some reason it had the same contents as `W-SU`. Doing `apt install --reinstall tzdata` and `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` fixed the problem.

Comment: The system default timezone is determined by file `/etc/localtime`, which is, depending on distribution, either a symlink to `/usr/share/zoneinfo/some/zone` or a copy of the appropriate file from the zoneinfo directory. If it is a link, and someone attempts to copy a new file over it to change the system default timezone, the overwrite will actually happen to the file the link points to. So I guess your Raspbian originally had UTC linked as the default timezone, and an attempt was made to switch it by `cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/W-SU /etc/localtime`, but it ended up overwriting `...zoneinfo/UTC`.

Comment: So you may wish to check that the system default timezone is still set correctly, and adjust it if necessary. If `/etc/localtime` is a symbolic link, you can either use e.g. `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/W-SU /etc/localtime` or just delete the old `/etc/localtime` first before copying/linking the desired timezone file in its place.

Comment: You're spot on! After `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` I now have a symlink to my desired default timezone, not a copy.

Comment: @Ruslan Raspberry is known for corrupting SD cards. Keep backups.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I think in this case it was my mistake – exactly as telcoM explains in a comment, not FS corruption. But I do have a backup in any case.

Answer (score 3):

The correct, standard and portable way to define via `$TZ` a time zone that is called UTC and is on (with 0 offset to) Universal Time all year round is with:

```
TZ=UTC0
```

That is self-contained and give the full specification for that timezone. That tells that the offset to UTC is 0 (all year round as there's no DST part specified) and the label (as reported by `date +%Z` for instance) is UTC.

The timezone specification as described by `TZ` can get more complicated as you can also embed the DST name and offset and the rules for when to change between summer and winter time. However, those rules are limited and in particular can't cover cases where the rules change change from one year to another (and in most countries, the rules have changed over time or use rules different from the first or last Sunday in some month).

That's why POSIX also specifies `TZ=:something` but with how `something` is handled left implementation defined to allow implementations to come up with a better way to define a timezone for real life zones.

On most systems, that's implemented using the [ICANN's tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (they also publish reference code to handle those).

So you'd use `TZ=:Europe/London` for instance for the mainland Britain timezone which covers timezone offsets and when the change for the current year and all past years in London.

In practice, `Europe/London` is interpreted as the path of a file relative to some `zoneinfo` directory (often `/usr/share/zoneinfo`).

In the tz database, there is also a `Etc/UTC` file (with `Etc/Universal` and `Etc/Zulu` links to it). `Etc/GMT` is defined the same way except the label is GMT all year round (with `Etc/GMT-0`, `Etc/GMT+0`, `Etc/Greenwich` as links).

So, you can do `TZ=:Etc/UTC` to get the same effect as `TZ=UTC0` except that the system needs to open that `Etc/UTC` file to find out about the simplest of TZ rules: 0 offset to UTC all year round.

On many (most?) systems, there's a `UTC` -> `Etc/UTC` symlink, so you can also do `TZ=:UTC`.

`TZ=UTC` itself is not POSIX, but here  in the absence of an offset being given, on most systems, it's interpreted as the same as `TZ=:UTC` (looks for the timezone definition in `/path/to/zoneinfo/UTC`. But if the tz database is not available, that won't work.

Also note that with `date` specifically, you can use the `-u` option to get UTC dates regardless of  what `$TZ` contains. `date -u` is equivalent to `TZ=UTC0 date`.